# AngularJS: how do I code an element directive with optional attribute parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing my first steps in AngularJS directives. Just set up this one as an exercise to output a product name:

```
.directive('productname', function (Prefs) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/partials/productname.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.brand = Prefs.owner;
            }
        }
    })
```

productname.html

```
<span class="productname"><span class="brand">{{brand}}</span> <span class="product" ng-transclude>{{productname}}</span></span>
```

and so the usage is plainly: `<productname>{{product.name}}</productname>`

Now, could someone tell me how I should go about making this directive configurable by adding a flag to output the productname linked?

The usage would be: `<productname linked>{{product.name}}</productname>` and the output/template would be:

```
<span class="productname"><a href="/edit/{{id}}"> <span class="brand">{{brand}}</span> <span class="product" ng-transclude>{{productname}}</span></a></span>
```

Seems complicated and I cannot quite figure out where the logic should be injected...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should use the `scope` property of the directive declaration. Also, you do not need `transclude` in this case. Like so:

```
.directive('productname', function (Prefs) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            product: "=",
            linked: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/partials/productname.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // scope.product and scope.linked are automatically set
            scope.brand = Prefs.owner;
        }
    }
})
```

And the template:

```
<span class="productname" ng-switch="linked">
    <a href="/edit/{{id}}" ng-switch-when="true">
        <span class="brand">{{brand}}</span>
        <span class="product">{{product.name}}</span>
    </a>
    <span ng-switch-default>
        <span class="brand">{{brand}}</span>
        <span class="product">{{product.name}}</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Call the template like so:

```
<productname product="product"></productname>
```

or:

```
<productname product="product" linked="'true'"></productname>
```

## Update

If you want to use the `linked` attribute as a flag, you could do that by using the `attrs` variable:

```
.directive('productname', function (Prefs) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            product: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/partials/productname.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // scope.product is automatically set
            scope.linked = typeof attrs.linked != 'undefined';
            scope.brand = Prefs.owner;
        }
    }
})
```

Call it like so:

```
<productname product="product" linked></productname>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alp. The property `linked` doesn't seem to get ever evaluated to true. I tried with '@' as well to no avail. Anyway, I now see how the conditional is approached, I might have been ineffective in mine because I didn't consider introducing interim `<span>` to hold the logic.

Comment: my bad. try setting a value for `linked`. for "=" an expression (a variable in the scope `linked="linked"` or a string `linked="'true'"`). for "@" a value (`linked="true"`)

Comment: Yep, now it works. I will however peruse to find a way convert the attribute into a flag.

Comment: i updated my answer for an example on how to do that

Comment: Nope :) That's what I've been through. You want a *single* negation of `attrs.linked` only. The mere presence of the attribute/property means its value is undefined which, when double-negated, leads to false. But thanks anyway!

Comment: `scope.linked = typeof attrs.linked != 'undefined';` works better for a flag property

Comment: I don't agree that you *should* use your own scope - this bit is optional. Even if you dont have your own scope any attributes will still be available on the link function and can be added to the scope, perhaps with a default value. eg.: scope.myDirectiveButtonText = attrs.myDirectiveButtonText || 'Save';